# How to get current file or folder path and filename with ahk2.x?

Tags: autohotkey

I am a novice, all I can search on the Internet are for AutoHotkey V1.

but i want use autohotkey V2 .

Get current choice file or folder path and filename on Windows 10 or 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to your original question:
How to get current file or folder path and filename?

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

; Create a group of the windows that contain files and/or folders:
; ahk_group ExplorerDesktopGroup
GroupAdd, ExplorerDesktopGroup, ahk_class ExploreWClass
GroupAdd, ExplorerDesktopGroup, ahk_class CabinetWClass
GroupAdd, ExplorerDesktopGroup, ahk_class Progman
GroupAdd, ExplorerDesktopGroup, ahk_class WorkerW

    return


#IfWinActive ahk_group ExplorerDesktopGroup

    ; Press Win+P in explorer or desktop 
    ; to get the path of the selected items in a message box

    #p::MsgBox % Explorer_GetSelection()

#IfWinActive

Explorer_GetSelection() {
    ; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=17&t=60403#p255169
    WinGetClass, winClass, % "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A")
    if !(winClass ~= "^(Progman|WorkerW|(Cabinet|Explore)WClass)$")
        Return   
    shellWindows := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW")
        shellFolderView := shellWindows.Item( ComObject(VT_UI4 := 0x13, SWC_DESKTOP := 0x8) ).Document
    else {
        for window in shellWindows 
        if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (shellFolderView := window.Document)
            break
   }
    for item in shellFolderView.SelectedItems
        result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.Path
    Return result
}
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to convert it to v2 using the [AHK-v2-script-converter](https://github.com/mmikeww/AHK-v2-script-converter):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#SingleInstance Force

; Create a group of the windows that contain files and/or folders:
; ahk_group ExplorerDesktopGroup
GroupAdd("ExplorerDesktopGroup", "ahk_class ExploreWClass")
GroupAdd("ExplorerDesktopGroup", "ahk_class CabinetWClass")
GroupAdd("ExplorerDesktopGroup", "ahk_class Progman")
GroupAdd("ExplorerDesktopGroup", "ahk_class WorkerW")

    return


#HotIf WinActive("ahk_group ExplorerDesktopGroup")

    ; Press Win+P in explorer or desktop 
    ; to get the path of the selected items in a message box

    #p:: MsgBox(Explorer_GetSelection())

#HotIf

Explorer_GetSelection() {
    ; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=17&t=60403#p255169
    result := ""
    winClass := WinGetClass("ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A"))
    if !(winClass ~= "^(Progman|WorkerW|(Cabinet|Explore)WClass)$")
        Return 
    shellWindows := ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW")
        shellFolderView := shellWindows.Item( ComValue(VT_UI4 := 0x13, SWC_DESKTOP := 0x8) ).Document
    else {
        for window in shellWindows 
        if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (shellFolderView := window.Document)
            break
   }
    for item in shellFolderView.SelectedItems
        result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.Path
    Return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have read the beginner's tutorial, I have seen the 1.x version, but I want the 2.x version of the code

Comment: As far as I know, [the v2 works differently](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/v2-changes.htm) and the translation from v1 to v2 is no easy task. It is recommended to [allow multiple versions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/howto/Install.htm) of AutoHotkey to co-exist.

Comment: Does not work - MsgBox is blank. This, however, works - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=518918#p518918